# React: Component Not Re-rendering After State Update

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm running into an issue where updating the state, `const [currentText, setCurrentText] = useState("");`, with the line `setCurrentText(script[property].text);` does not rerender the component.
I have verified that the state has in fact been updated, but the component just will not re-render with the new values.

```
  function nextScriptLine() {
    for (const property in script) {
      if (script[property].index === count) {
        setCount((count) => {
          return count + 1;
        });
        // console.log(script[property]); correct entry
        break;
      }
    }
    for (const property in script) {
      if (script[property].index == count) {
        setCurrentText(script[property].text);
        // console.log(currentText); correct and expented value
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

```
        <TextBox
          input={currentText === "" ? script.introText.text : currentText}
          toggleWithSource={toggleWithSource}
          nextScriptLine={nextScriptLine}
          disableSound={currentText === ""}
        />
```

> Textbox component

```
export default function TextBox({
  input,
  toggleWithSource,
  nextScriptLine,
  disabledSound,
}) {
  //   useEffect(() => {
  //     let tempObj = {};
  //     for (const property in script) {
  //       if (!property.read) {
  //         tempObj = script[property];
  //         setScript({ [property]: { read: true } });
  //         break;
  //       }
  //     }
  //   }, [script]);

  return (
    <span className="gameText">
      {textHandler(input, toggleWithSource, disabledSound)}
      <SubdirectoryArrowLeftIcon onClick={() => nextScriptLine()} />
    </span>
  );
}
```

The chrome developer tools, react components viewer, shows correct props and state after calling nextScriptLine():

```
props

disableSound
:
false

input
:
"Oh dear, you appear to have set yourself on <span class='cast'>fire</span> and died. Let's try that again.\\nTry casting <span class='cast>self fire extend</span>'"
nextScriptLine
:
ƒ nextScriptLine() {}
toggleWithSource
:
ƒ toggleWithSource() {}
new entry
:
```

I have read through a number of forums, stackoverflow questions/answer, and read multiple medium.com articles on the issue with no success. I have tried useEffect(which causes an infinite loop, which still doesn't have the updated state values anyways), state updater(waiting for state updates etc), and the only thing that seems to work is manually updating state via setCurrentText.

I'm starting to think the typewriter-effect npm package being async is messing with this somehow, because the rest of the state updates and rerenders work fine.

> I'm writing this project because I've become rusty after being stagnant from programming for a while, so ANY advice or tips are more than welcome. Thank you in advance!

> Update

After commenting out the typewriter component and leaving just `return input` the components re-render correctly. I would still like to use the typewriter-effect package. Is there anything I can do to get this to work?

Typewrite code:

```
export default function textHandler(input, toggleWithSource, disableSound) {
  <Typewriter
    onInit={(typewriter) => {
      typewriter
        .changeDelay(20)
        .typeString(input)
        .callFunction(() => {
          if (disableSound == false) {
            toggleWithSource();
          }
          alert(input);
        })
        .start();
    }}
  />
}
```

Tried another typewriter effect package, same issue. I've come to the conclusion that this is something to do with async issues for sure. Due to the lack of documentation and my knowledge, I will probably be moving forward without these packages. As unfortunate as that is, I just don't know how to have the code wait for the typewriter effects to finish I'm assuming.

Comment: Please create an online sandbox that demonstrates the issue. It's difficult to say what's wrong based on the information you've provided so far.

Comment: Yeah, I get that.. It's pretty hard to replicate.. See my updated information: The components now work without the typewriter-effect component. I think it may have something to do with it being somewhat async.

Thank you for the reply!!